# How to render child window before objects?

Tags: direct3d, direct3d11

I am using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff729722.aspx) example. I made a child window and I want to render it as before the objects, like a background. I am using direct3d and createwindow.

Comment: Draw the child window in an offscreen texture and use it as a background

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. I read somewhere that I should render a plane using 2 triangles and render the texture on it, but I didn't found any example.

Comment: So I am trying to draw a bitmap on a rectangle like in this (https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/windows/desktop/Direct2D/how-to-draw-a-bitmap) tutorial, but it's not working.